# AIML and python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiml

Hey I just started looking into programming Chatbots with python3 is there an interpreter for AIML files for python3. I tried looking in pip but I can only find it supported for python 2?

Comment: what you were done can explain briefly, or try (pip3 install aiml) otherwise download tar file go into it and run (python3 setup.py install), it works.

Comment: @ShivaGuntuku AIML does install to python3 for me however when I try and import the module it returns "No module named 'Kernel'". I assumed this was because it was incompatible with python3. Is this some problem with my install of python3? Or have I missed some dependency I need to install first?

Comment: i think it's supported for python2.7 only,not supporting in python3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/weddige/pyaiml3 to enable AIML interpreter in python 3. I have tested it in python3.5.2 and it worked.